# how to insert flag for column match and non-match using read_sql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am trying to insert a flag (match/non-match) after the comparing columns for 2 different tables. I am able to compare the two mysql table columns ***but not getting how I can insert a flag column and get the status (match/non-match)***

The below is an example, consider 2 mysql tables:

tab1:

```
email
abc@gamil.com
xyz@email.com
ijk@gmail.com
ghi@gmail.com
pqr@gmail.com
yup@gmail.com
```

tab2:

```
email
ijk@gmail.com
yup@gmail.com
```

tab3:

```
email
xyz@email.com
pqr@gmail.com
```

Now I want output like this:

```
email           valid
abc@gamil.com   non-match
xyz@email.com   match
ijk@gmail.com   match
ghi@gmail.com   non-match
pqr@gmail.com   match
yup@gmail.com   match
```

*Tried with pandas:*

```
data_2=pd.read_sql("select tab1.*,if(tab2.email  is not null ,'MATCH','NONMATCH') stataus from tab1  left join tab2 on tab1.email=tab2.email ",con=engine)
```

**getting incorrect syntax for multiple table comparision :**

*but how can i do for 2 tables :

tried this way

data_2=pd.read_sql("select tab1.*,if(tab2.email and  tab3.email is not null ,'MATCH','NONMATCH') stataus from tab1  left join tab2 on tab1.email=tab2.email  left join tab3 on  tab1.email=tab3.email",con=engine)*

Answer (score 1):

Can be solved purely in SQL.

```
SELECT tab1.email 
  CASE WHEN tab2.email IS NULL THEN 'non-match' ELSE 'valid' END
FROM tab1 left join  tab2 on tab1.email =tab2.email"
```

Case / When is how you assign a value conditionally in mysql

Comment: does this work with pymysql.curosr or pandas.....as i am getting an error"error in syntax"

Comment: Sorry copy paste error. Check now. If you get any errors, please post the complete error message

Comment: SELECT tab1.*, if(tab1.email=tab2.email,'nonmatch','match')status from tab1 left join tab2 on tab1.email=tab2.email

Comment: It's case when that you are supposed to use. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close with first query, but forgot to take into account the other table:

```
select tab1.email, (tab2.email is not null) as is_match
from tab1
  left join tab2
on tab1.email = tab2.email;
```

I would also use boolean column instead of storing strings 'valid' and 'non-match'

Comment: Thanx  a lot got it but in place of boolean values how can i attempt to write match/non-match any solution for that

Comment: @e4c5 answer works well with that, but if it's not a homework assignment, boolean values should be preferred because they will take less space and better represent logic of the program

Answer (score 0):

data_2=pd.read_sql("select tab1.,if(tab2.email is not null or tab3.email is not null ,'MATCH','NONMATCH') stataus from tab1 left join tab2 on tab1.email=tab2.email left join tab3 on tab1.email=tab3.email",con=engine)